# fswrite with full 777 server protocol. Secure?

Tags: javascript, php, security, cookies

I have a question about the security of a server when the 777 Permissions are open.

This is the code:

```
<?php
// collect the cookie - save the data 
if(!isset($_COOKIE["markertype"])) {
    echo "Cookie named markertype is not set!";
} else {
   echo "Cookie markertype is set!<br>";
   echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE["markertype"];
   $file = 'newfile.txt';
   // Open the file to get existing content
   $current = file_get_contents($file);
   // Append a new person to the file
   $current .= $_COOKIE["markertype"];
   // Write the contents back to the file
   file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Basically the system allows users to do stuff in javascript, I then set a cookie in JS with some user information that they put in the system. I then send that to PHP via a cookie to store this information on the server. The problem was that the server didn't have the permission to write to a file, so i proceeded to give full 777 access to the entire directory.

I think this opens me up to full XSS attacks and more, what is my alternative or can i secure the server in a different way? the server is NOT mine, therefore I only have certain access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah 777 does cause some security holes, however it can be used on a different
directory on your server, for instance if you have a public_http folder, then make that 777 permissions then that is a HUGE issue, but instead you could make a non-public accessible folder full 777 and save your data to that.

This still isn't 100% secure because really your data should be off-site or remotely stored in a database, but if it's just for research then that is fine.

hope this helped.
H

Comment: yes it is for research and i will change it to how you said, thank you so much!!